# Log in field with a specific input

Tags: php, web, preg-match, string-matching

I'd like to make a registration input field that only accepts certain types of email addresses (e.g., one that only accepts email addresses that end with `@yahoo.com`) so that I can provide some security in terms of who can access my website (e.g., I want to only accept email addresses that are from students from my school, i.e., they must end in `@school.edu`).

Here's what i have so far, but this does not discriminate for a specific type of email:

```
<?php

    // configuration
    require("../includes/config.php"); 

    // if form was submitted
    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
    {
        // validate inputs
        if (empty($_POST["username"]))
        {
            apologize("You must provide a username.");
        }
        else if (empty($_POST["password"]))
        {
            apologize("You must provide a password.");
        }
        else if (empty($_POST["confirmation"]) || $_POST["password"] != $_POST["confirmation"])
        {
            apologize("Those passwords did not match.");
        }

        // try to register user
        $results = query("INSERT INTO users (username, hash, cash) VALUES(?, ?, 10000.0000)",
            $_POST["username"], crypt($_POST["password"])
        );
        if ($results === false)
        {
            apologize("That username appears to be taken.");
        }

        // get new user's ID
        $rows = query("SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() AS id");
        if ($rows === false)
        {
            apologize("Can't find your ID.");
        }
        $id = $rows[0]["id"];

        // log user in
        $_SESSION["id"] = $id;

        // redirect to portfolio
        redirect("/");
    }
    else
    {
        // else render form
        render("register_form.php", ["title" => "Register"]);
    }

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [substr()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) function combined with the [strrpos()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrpos.php) to get the last part of the email:

```
if(substr($email, strrpos($email, "@")) == "@school.edu") {
  //all good
}
```

Once you have done that, you can email them a confirmation link to the email provided to make sure it's not a bogus one.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use simple regex to verify user's email

```
if(preg_match('#^(.*)\@school\.edu$#', $_POST['email'])) {
    echo 'email is valid';
} else {
    echo 'this is not valid email!';
}
```